# Creating a plugin for code hinting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working with an internally-developed scripting language that some prof and his team have created for an academic project. There's documentation that show function signatures of the existing classes, but for outsiders like me, I'm constantly referring to documentation. Also, in the summer, more helpers will join and I bet they will all suffer from the same problem. So I'd like to write something in Eclipse to help with code hinting and completion, like many languages have.

I haven't programmed eclipse add-ons before, so can someone give me hints how I would generally take the function signatures from their documentation and get code hinting from it. I realize I may need to make changes to the documentation to use it for what I need. But any hints or sample projects would be appreciated. I'm not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). With Xtext you can define a domain specific language and generate an editor for it. Here you can find a [brief tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/020-domainmodel-step-by-step.php).